# Validating CollectionType array of object Symfony 4.2

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4

I am creating a form that can hold undefined amount of collections of inputs inside, which appear after pressing button "Add". I was following this documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html and everything seems to work fine. I can add, delete, save and edit main form and collections of inputs. Now I am trying to validate inputs, but I am having problems with validating CollectionType entities.
For main form inputs I am using validation as following :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 */
private $name;
```

And for CollectionType my validation looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\Collection(
 *     fields = {
 *         "name" = {
 *              @Assert\NotBlank
 *              @Assert\Type("string")
 *             )
 *         },
 *         "desc" = {
 *              @Assert\NotBlank
 *              @Assert\Type("string")
 *             )
 *         }
 *     },
 *     allowMissingFields = false,
 *     allowExtraFields = false
 * )
 * })
 *
 */
private $tags;
```

I am getting this error:

```
This value should be of type array|(Traversable&ArrayAccess).
```

I don't know if this helps, but by dumping form error I can see this :

```
-propertyPath: "data.tags[0]"
        -invalidValue: Tag {#850 ▼
          -id: null
          -name: null
          -desc: null
        }
```

I have defined validation to Tag entity variables too, but it still doesn't work.

If I remove "@Assert\All" part I am getting :

```
This field is missing.
```

error for data.tags[name] and data.tags[desc].
As well as :

```
This field was not expected.
```

for data.tags[0]

EDIT:
I ended up creating custom validator according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

these rules:

```
* @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\Collection(
 *     fields = {
 *         "name" = {
 *              @Assert\NotBlank
 *              @Assert\Type("string")
 *             )
 *         },
 *         "desc" = {
 *              @Assert\NotBlank
 *              @Assert\Type("string")
 *             )
 *         }
 *     },
 *     allowMissingFields = false,
 *     allowExtraFields = false
 * )
 * })
```

should be put in the `Tag` entity, on each field you want to be validated

Comment: They already have  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 */ but they are not validating in CollectionType